# How display 'dropdown-menu' without submit button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like create and display menu for my element only after click in small button.

I have a small button which run function "doAction"

```
<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" ng-click="doAction(\'OpenMenu\', $event)"></i>
```

In my function 'doAction' a would like fetch position X Y from event mouse click and display in this place my menu.
Almost everything work... I have problem with 'dropdown-menu'.
More precisely, i see button discribed above and button from this code (id=test):

```
 var menu = angular.element('<div class="dropdown">' +
                '<button id="test" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>'+
                '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'+
                '<li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>'+
                '<li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>'+
                '<li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>'+
                '</ul>'+
                '</div>');

            menu.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                left: event.clientX,
                top: event.clientY,
                zIndex: '999'
            });

            var body = angular.element(document).find('body').eq(0);
            body.append(menu);
```

Now, i have to click on first button 'fa-ellipsis-h' later button "test", and only then i see my menu.
I don't know how remove button 'id = test' from variable "menu" and open menu immediately after the press first  button 'fa fa-ellipsis-h'.

Comment: why don't you use angular ui bootstrap

Comment: Can you explain? I'm newbie...

Comment: check this [ui bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure that you need those single quotes escaped in your function? I copied and pasted your HTML into a jsbin, and it immediately failed because of that.

If I understand what you're asking, you want your menu to open after the first click, instead of after clicking the `<i>` element, and THEN clicking the test button.

It is working for me here in this bin: [working example](http://jsbin.com/rarawefena/edit?html,js,output)
`<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" data-ng-click="doAction('OpenMenu', $event)">Menu</i>`

Clicking the  immediately opens the menu (I added in some text for those elements, because I don't have the fontawesome library included).